# Task queue using rabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

We have a system that receive payment information for invoices from the bank system. It works like that:

1. Invoice is created in our system
2. Payment for the invoice is done through Bank system. Bank system request invoice details from our system and it returns the invoice details
3. Bank system goes through payment process, and sends payment details to our system and it will wait for confirm message for 30 seconds. If the bank system does not receive confirm message within 30 seconds, bank cancels the payment but does not inform our system about cancellation.
4. Our system receives the payment info, and saves the payment. Then
   sends the confirm message to bank. But sometimes, because of network
   or system issue, confirm message won't be delivered within 30
   seconds and we became unaware of cancelled message status.

So, the problem is our system saves the payment but sometimes cannot respond on time for payment confirmation request (within 30 secs), in this case, bank cancels the payment and our system doesn't know the payment is cancelled.

I have developed a solution that checks an each payment if the payment is successful (after 30 seconds of receiving the payment) by sending a request to check payment method Bank provided. Tasks (send the payment id to check_payment method of bank system - it returns payment status) are executed in separate threads using thread pool of Spring framework. But I am afraid that it is not the best solution as there is a risk of being full of thread pool when network failure happens .

What solutions would you recommend? Can we use RabbitMQ for this issue?

Comment: I am not sure if RabbitMQ is suitable for this project. On the other hand one has to consider the risks involved with the deployment of more software products that can be potentially risky, and I mean security risks, vulnerability.

Comment: Please state better the actual problem you are trying to solve and the architecture in mind. What part of the process is negatively affected by network outages? What are the tasks you are executing in parallel?

Comment: @noxdafox thanks for the comment. I've updated my answer. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially implementing stateful orchestration. I would recommend looking into [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) that capable of supporting your use case with minimal effort.

Cadence offers a lot of other advantages over using queues for task processing.

- Built it exponential retries with unlimited expiration interval
- Failure handling. For example it allows to execute a task that notifies another service if both updates couldn't succeed during a configured interval.
- Support for long running heartbeating operations
- Ability to implement complex task dependencies. For example to implement chaining of calls or compensation logic in case of unrecoverble failures ([SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html))
- Gives complete visibility into current state of the update. For example when using queues all you know if there are some messages in a queue and you need additional DB to track the overall progress. With Cadence every event is recorded.
- Ability to cancel an update in flight.

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over Cadence programming model.